# css JavaScript widget overrides my stylesheet

Tags: css

Morning,

I am writing a site that includes a widget via javascript.

For some reason the widget has an embedded line in the stylesheet:

```
* { color:#000 }
```

Because the widget loads after the page that seems to overide all the text within my page.

I have added the !important to all the styles within the sites css file that need to be a different color, but this does not work.

I have asked the widget supplier why he has that line but because so many black & white sites use his widget hes not keen on removing the line.

Is there any way of overriding this or removing this line (via jquery maybe) ?

many thanks

Comment: Try loading the script at the top of the page, though it might hit on site's performance

Comment: what is the widget name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about being a bit more specific than the widget? Using for instance the ID of a wrapping div, or body?

Comment: @VenomVendor I changed it within a few seconds :)

Comment: I have now added ids to the area which has inverse colors and this has worked. Although when i applied to the whole area class it did not work. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @SouthCoastWeb You need to be more specific than `* {}` which is applied to each element. A simple class won't be enough. But you should be able to do `.class p {}` etc...which is more specific than `* {}`

Answer (score 2):

If you call that stylesheet from a remote location, just download the css file, change that line, upload it to *your* server and call it from there.